# DSYM file is not uploaded to firebase while running build in azure CI Environment

Tags: ios, firebase, azure-pipelines, crashlytics, dsym

I'm trying to upload dsym file to firebase. I've followed [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) tutorial. Everything worked fine when i was building app from xcode. Issue occurred when i tried to do it using [azure pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops).
I have added build phase to my xcode build. It looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg42S.png)

After running it in CI environment i got this result:

`Debug mode enabled 
Running in a CI Environment 
Not running in an instance of Xcode.app 
Crashlytics is not installed 
Google App ID: 1:xxxx
Platform: ios 
DSYM Paths: ["/.../BuildProductsPath/Test-iphoneos/App.app.dSYM"] 
Validation succeeded. Exiting because upload-symbols was run in validation mode`

But after testings my app, I receive crash report with missing dsym in Crashlytics dashboard.

Is there any way to add more logging or check already uploaded dsym files to firebase? Maybe i've missed some additional configurations.

**EDIT-1:**

My build pipeline looks like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-latest'

trigger:
- master

steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
  clean: true

- script: /usr/local/bin/pod install
  displayName: 'pod install using a script'

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'xxx.p12'
    certPwd: '$(P12Password)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'xxx.mobileprovision'

- task: ios-bundle-version@1
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 'App/Info.plist'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    versionName: '1.0.$(Build.BuildId)'
    printFile: true

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'clean build archive'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/App.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'App'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    provisioningProfileName: 'xxx'
    args: 'SWIFT_VERSION=5.0'
    useXcpretty: false


- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.ipa'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'drop' 
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

In pod file i have those lines:

```
#Firebase
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

Comment: From the error log, it seems that the `Crashlytics` doesn't install. You could try to install the via [pod file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#add-sdk). Since the script could work on local xcode, you may try to use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops).

Comment: You could share the build definition in Azure Devops .You could also set the variable: `system.debug=true` to check the detailed debug log.

Comment: Any ideas why Crashlytics is not installed? I have step for installing it and in build log i can see that it's completed: "Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (4.2.0)".

Comment: Sorry. Not many ideas. The pod file is same as the doc. But the log shows the FirebaseCrashlytics hasn't been installed. You may check if the  installation path is correct.  From your description, you could run the app on local machine, could you please try to use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops) to run the same pipeline. By the way,  is the log you shared all error logs? You could share more about the error message.

Comment: Can you try from the terminal and see of that actually works fine?

Comment: The issue was with compileBitcode flag set to 'Yes' in exportOptions.plist file. Thanks guys for help!

Answer (score 1):

Issue appeared to be in the export option plist file, which was set to autogenerate in 'task: Xcode@5'. In this file there is a flag compileBitcode. By default it was set to 'Yes' and it was the issue. After exporting the .ipa file with this option, dsym files produced during build are not valid.

In my case i've just added custom ExportOptionsTestEnv.plist file. You can generate this file by archiving your app from xcode and distribute it with ad hoc configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>destination</key>
    <string>export</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>YOURBUNDLEID</key>
        <string>PROVISIONINGPROFILENAME</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>Apple Distribution</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>TEAMID</string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And changed build configuration to look like this:

```
    - task: Xcode@5
      inputs:
        actions: 'clean build archive'
        xcWorkspacePath: '**/App.xcworkspace'
        scheme: 'App'
        packageApp: true
        exportOptions: 'plist'
        exportOptionsPlist: 'ExportOptions/ExportOptionsTestEnv.plist'
        signingOption: 'manual'
        provisioningProfileName: 'xxx'
        args: 'SWIFT_VERSION=5.0'
        useXcpretty: false
```

Just have on mind that this solution won't work with TestFlight and AppleStore, because those services require compileCode flag enabled.

Possible solution to this would be fastlane deployments. In documentation they write that this is supported: [upload_symbols_to_crashlytics](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_symbols_to_crashlytics/)